# Spreadsheet RegexReplace but exclude non-number

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to RegexReplace but only for number.

[image]

I tried this formula, but it didn't go as I expected:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, ":<BR CLASS="""">[0-9]", ": [0-9]")
```

The link of sheet is [`here`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j6X0YtpTz9pnwa9woR-Q1tkStSaCfmQ67f11PiBwLBM/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\d+` (or `[0-9]+`) to match **one or more** digits, and a capturing group (a pair of unescaped parentheses) around the pattern you want to keep, with a backreference to the group value in the replacement:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A2, ":<BR CLASS="""">(\d+)", ": $1")
```

[image]

*Details*:

- `:<BR CLASS=` - a fixed string
- `""""` - a `""` pattern (since a `"` char should be escaped with another `"` in a string literal in Google Sheets formula)
- `>` - a `>` char
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` refers to the group value): one or more digits.